# Inserting numbers in a table automatically

Tags: table

I would like to have a function that inserts a table with 16 columns and 5 rows.

Then insert numbers from 1 to 15 in the first row (last column leaving it empty), and numbers 16 to 31 in the second column.

To make the table I use `(table-insert 16 5 3 1)`.  But I do not know how to fill the first two rows with the mentioned numbers  automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know virtually nothing about the `table` package. I did `C-h f table-insert` to read what it does and then I did `C-h f table-<TAB>` and got a completion table. Scanning the completion table, I saw `table-insert-sequence` so I clicked on it and found that it does indeed fill out cells of a table sequentially. The rest was reading the details, looking at the examples and a bit of trial and error. That's basically what I *always* do with a new package and in this case I stopped here. But if I decide the package is useful, I then read the manual (if there is one) and/or the commentary in the file (`table.el` in this case) if there is one. Then over time and if necessary, I read (parts of) the code. I hope that's a useful description for how to approach new packages and that it will prove useful to you in the future.

Here's a function:

```el
(defun my/table-make-and-stuff ()
   (table-insert 16 3 5 1)
   (table-insert-sequence "1" 15 1 1 'center)
   (table-forward-cell 16)
   (table-insert-sequence "16" 16 1 1 'center))
```

I assume that you mistyped the last word of the second paragraph of your question, IOW that you meant "row" instead of "column".

Editorializing a bit, I find [Org mode tables](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tables.html#Tables) much more useful and intuitive, even though they have some limitations in comparison (no multiline cells e.g.)

Comment: Correct, I meant to say as you described.